# $A^TAx = A^Tb$ is always consistent, independent of $Ax=b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix, $x$ is a vector of unknowns and $b$ is a vector of know entries. Whether $Ax=b$ is consistent or not ,But $A^TAx=B$ is always consistent.

Is that above statement correct? or Am I missing anything?

Comment: What's $B$? If $A$ is a real $m \times n$ matrix and $b$ is an $m \times 1$ column vector then the linear system $A^T Ax = A^T b$ is guaranteed to be consistent. A vector $x$ satisfies this equation if and only if $x$ is a minimizer of the function $f(x) = \|Ax - b \|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you mean $A^Tb$ by "B". Whether $Ax = b$ is asking if b is in the image of the linear map which is multiplication by A. If b is zero, asking for the solutions to $Ax = b$ is the same as asking what x's are in the kernel of "multiplication by A" (we call this linear map $L_A$ by the way). By multiplying both sides by $A^T$ and asking what x's solve the equation $A^TAx = A^Tb$, we should assume A is noninvertible (otherwise it is the same question as what the solutions to Ax = b are). You can also think of this as the kernel of the linear map $(L_A)^TL_A(x) - A^Tb$ (where $(L_A)^T = L_{A^T}$).Additionally,

if $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $b = \begin{pmatrix} b_1\\b_2\end{pmatrix}$, and $x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}$, $A^TA = A^Tb$ iff $Ax = b$ (you should check that). So the relationship between the two equations can be more or less whatever, other than the fact that we must have $Ax = b$ implies $A^TAx = A^Tb$ (by just multiplying both sides of the first equation by $A^T$).

(also I am assuming the entries are in a subfield of the complex numbers).

Comment: Ok yeah true, I will remove that part.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with the reals (complex is similar) we have
$\mathbb{R}^m = {\cal R}A \oplus \ker A^T$.

In particular, we can decompose $b$ (uniquely) as $b=b_1+b_2$ where
$b_1 \in {\cal R}A, b_2 \in\ker A^T$.

Hence there is some $x$ such that $Ax = b_1$, and $Ax-b_1 = b_2$ and so
$A^T(Ax-b) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the underlying field be $\mathbb{R}$.
It seems that you are a beginner, so this approach may be more friendly.

First is to observe that $A^TAX=0 \iff AX = 0$. (I shall leave this bit of work to you.) So if a linearly independent set $\langle X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_r\rangle$, where $r=\mathrm{rank}\;A$, spans the column space of the matrix $A$, then $\langle AX_1,AX_2,\cdots,AX_r\rangle$ spans the column space of $A^T$ as well. Since $A^Tb$ is always a vector in the column space of $A^T$, it can be derived by a linear combination of $\langle X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_r\rangle$.

Comment: Just as the assumption indicates, if the underlying field extends to $\mathbb{C}$, this assertion may not hold. Let's assign $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ i & i\end{pmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$. $A^TA = \mathbf{0}$, while $A^Tb = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.